# How to avoid having to specify public dependencies twice when creating packages in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

Currently having some trouble understanding the proper way to create packages with CMake.

I am trying to build a library with various compilation options, and use it as a relocatable package.
I have a `CMakeLists.txt` that is similar to this:

```cmake
add_library(Lib lib.cpp lib.h)

if (WITH_FOO)
    find_package(Foo REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(Lib Foo::Foo)
endif()

if (WITH_BAR)
    find_package(Bar REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(Lib Bar::Bar)
endif()

if (WITH_OTHER_TARGET)
    add_library(OtherTarget other_target.cpp other_target.h)
    target_link_libraries(Lib OtherTarget)
endif()

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS Lib
    EXPORT LibTargets
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
    INCLUDES DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
)

install(EXPORT LibTargets
    FILE LibTargets.cmake
    NAMESPACE Lib::
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/Lib
)

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)

configure_package_config_file(
    LibConfig.cmake.in
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/LibConfig.cmake
    INSTALL_DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/Lib
)

install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/LibConfig.cmake
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/Lib
)
```

From what I understand, all public dependencies should be listed in the `LibConfig.cmake` file.

What is the correct way to do this?
I could do something like this:

```
@PACKAGE_INIT@

include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/LibTargets.cmake")

include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)

if (@WITH_FOO@)
    find_dependency(Foo)
endif()

if (@WITH_BAR@)
    find_dependency(Bar)
endif()
```

But this seems very error-prone, as I would have to remember to add the `find_dependency` for every new public dependency I add.

I also tried using the `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` property of the `Lib` target, but this seems rather unreliable because it is cluttered with my own targets and other stuff like `-lpthread`.

I am a bit lost. What is the correct way to do this? Am I doing this all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is correct to have in the config file `find_dependency` calls for every `find_package` call in the project's `CMakeLists.txt`.

If you have many conditional `find_package` calls and want to avoid corresponding conditional `find_dependency` calls in the config file, then you could prepare some **variable** for collect all these calls "on-line".

```cmake
# This variable will contain list of `find_dependency` calls to be added into the config file.
set(config_dependencies)

if (WITH_FOO)
    find_package(Foo REQUIRED)
    # Add corresponding `find_dependency` into the config file
    set(config_dependencies "${config_dependencies}\nfind_dependency(Foo)")

    target_link_libraries(Lib Foo::Foo)
endif()

if (WITH_BAR)
    find_package(Bar REQUIRED)
    # Add corresponding `find_dependency` into the config file
    set(config_dependencies "${config_dependencies}\nfind_dependency(Bar)")

    target_link_libraries(Lib Bar::Bar)
endif()
```

So in the config file's template you would have

```
# ...
include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)

@config_dependencies@
```

---

Instead of a variable one could use a GLOBAL property, which could be updated from any scope, not just from the top-level `CMakeLists.txt`:

```cmake
# This variable will contain list of `find_dependency` calls to be added into the config file.
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY config_dependencies "")

# Convenient function for add find_dependency call into the property
# Usage:
#
# add_find_dependency(package_name [args...])
function(add_find_dependency package_name)
  # Combine package name and other parameters into the space-separated string.
  string(JOIN " " args_string ${package_name} ${ARGN})
  set_property(GLOBAL APPEND_STRING PROPERTY config_dependencies
    "\nfind_dependency(${args_string})"
  )
endfunction()

if (WITH_FOO)
    find_package(Foo REQUIRED)
    add_find_dependency(Foo)
    target_link_libraries(Lib Foo::Foo)
endif()

if (WITH_BAR)
    find_package(Bar REQUIRED)
    add_find_dependency(Bar)
    target_link_libraries(Lib Bar::Bar)
endif()

# ... from inner `CMakeLists.txt`
if (WITH_BAZ)
    find_package(Baz REQUIRED COMPONENTS aaa bbb)
    add_find_dependency(Baz COMPONENTS aaa bbb)
    target_link_libraries(Lib Baz::Baz)
endif()

# ...

# Prepare variables for creating the config file
get_property(config_dependencies GLOBAL PROPERTY config_dependencies)

configure_package_config_file(...)
```

Template for the config file will be the same:

```
# ...
include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)

@config_dependencies@
```